# Using return value vs out parameters

Tags: c#

It's very popular to see code like this:

```
bool DoSomething([some arguments]);
```

You can't understand the result of this method by looking at its name (it could actually be a `void`).

What's the best approach to refactor such kind of methods?  What I have in mind is something like this:

```
void DoSomething([some argumens],out bool everythingIsOk);
```

What do you think?

**EDIT**

It seems that so many people prefer

```
bool TryDoSomething();
```

rather than

```
void DoSomething(out bool success);
```

But what if a method is going to have a result instead of being `void`?  Can we use `int.TryParse` pattern or we should return the result and throw an exception if something goes wrong?

Comment: Use exceptions unless you need performance and this private method is just a helper.

Answer (score 24):

You’re asking the wrong question. In reality, both methods are bad. If you need the success message, either throw an exception on failure (but only if this is really an *exceptional* scenario, *or* return the success and *indicate this in the method name*. For instance, by calling the method `TrySomething`.

In general, your example sounds like the method is actually doing two distinct things, otherwise there would be no confusion in the first place. But this is *code smell* anyway: **every method should have only one purpose**. If that is the case, then the meaning of the return value is always clear, no need to give it a name.

Answer (score 22):

I would go with

```
bool TryDoSomething([some arguments]);
```

, following the naming logic of [`Int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).

Comment: Please don't use this. Exceptions are meant for this. If you're worrying about performance because of Exception creation check the preconditions before calling this method.

Comment: @MrHappy: Exceptions absolutely *are not* meant for this. Exceptions are meant for *exceptional conditions*, meaning they are conditions that should not normally occur while your program is executing. Your code should always preemptively check to see if the data is valid. Exceptions are not meant to serve as lazy validation routines.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: Tell Microsoft that. `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse` are prime examples. TryParse is only here because of performance reasons. Should I check that the string I want to parse only contains characters that can be converted to numbers? No I expect my input to be valid. If it's not valid, that is an exceptional condition, and a `FormatException` will be thrown by `int.Parse` which I can handle in a seperate catch clause. I can't miss an exceptions, whereas I _can_ miss a boolean return value.

Comment: Totally agree. +1

Comment: @MrHappy Nonsense, `TryParse` is *not* there for performance reasons. Rather, it was retrofitted once they saw that throwing an exception when parsing is highly inappropriate. Eric Lippert [acknowledges](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) that `int.Parse` was an “unfortunate design decision”.

Comment: I agree with this only for trivial cases, like the `TryParse` method, where the meaning of the output is well-known. I certainly wouldn't build an application full of methods starting with `Try` that return `bool`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm I didn't know that (good article btw). Allright bad example, but I think my point still stands. Invalid input is an exceptional condition, for which an `Exception` should be thrown, not a `false` returned. Unless `TryDoSomething([some args])` is actually a `TryParseSomething(out [some args])`

Comment: @MrHappy User input is inherently untrusted. Since you *always* need to perform validation, the validation isn’t an exceptional condition. You are *expecting* potential failure. I’m not saying that `TryParse` is optimal (it’s not, the entire interface sucks) – there are much better ways of modelling this but C# supports them poorly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree that you always need to validate input. I'm saying that _invalid_ input is an exceptional condition. I always code as if everything is valid, and handle the exceptional cases in seperate blocks, namely the catch clauses.

Comment: @MrHappy But this isn’t what exceptions are good at. They are good at indicating exceptional conditions that don’t necessarily have to be handled by the caller, but instead passed on to higher levels. This is **never** true when parsing input. Faulty input should always be handled straightaway. Think of it this way: if you need to *always* put a `try` block around a call, then exceptions aren’t appropriate here. They are only appropriate when the caller can usually skip the `try` and let exceptions bubble up. Read Eric Lippert’s explanation that I linked above.

Comment: @MrHappy sorry for the belated reply. I think you make a good point, but I disagree; I would have a mixed approach - as an example, throw if the current state did not allow the action and return false if the conditions were not met. I much prefer `bool TrySendEmail(...){}` to a void-returning that throws an exception. (I might still throw from inside TrySendEmail, if for example a null address was supplied.)

Comment: @ANeves Would you also like a `bool TryOpenFile(string fileName, out File stream){}`?

Comment: @MrHappy I would not; but that doesn't mean `stream != null`, which is not supposed to happen in normal situations. My point is that my calling methods should only get exceptions that are the responsibility of (or consequences of) either them or someone in an outer scope; so if they are sure that all arguments passed to `SendEmail` are valid and the method returns no resource, my rationale is that I should not need to wrap the calls in try-catches. It feels wrong. IMO external methods should not have to be aware of InvalidSMTPSSLTokenException or whatever - only SendEmail.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Eric Lippert is wrong. As far as I'm concerned exceptions are a much better way to handle what he calls "vexing" exceptions then error returns are. Of course, you and Eric can disagree with me. The thing is that you neither you nor Eric provide reasoning for why you think exceptions are bad for these cases, you merely reiterate the position that they are.

Comment: @Winston I’m observing that you – unlike Eric and me (see above!), in fact – don’t provide any evidence for your position either, merely reiterating your position. Of course “error returns” are an almost as bad way of handing this case. A good design would have used monads (more specifically, option values).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, what evidence have you presented for you position? The only thing I see is the claim "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances" without any reason given for that. Fair enough, I haven't presented any either. I'd say that I prefer exceptions because they have a sane(r) default then error codes. But I'll agree something else perhaps monads would be even better, but sadly not supported in enough languages.

Comment: @Winston “Think of it this way: if you need to always put a try block around a call, then exceptions aren’t appropriate here. They are only appropriate when the caller can usually skip the try and let exceptions bubble up.” The point being: if you always have to catch exceptions (as you would have to in the case of input checking) they have no objective advantage over a boolean return value. The whole point of exceptions, their design goal, is the ability to be caught way up the call stack.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, actually I think there still is an objective advantage of an exception over a boolean return value. If I fail to check my boolean return code my program will silently fail which is very bad. If I fail to catch an exception, my program will probably die, which is not good but a lot better then a silent failure.

Comment: Additionally, almost no function should always be in a try/catch. For example, a `parseInt` function could be used on input which I'm already sure is a valid integer. If that's the case and a letter somehow got into my string, I want the exception behavior, to report the error up because I've got a bug not the error code behavior which will just carry on and mask the real cause of the bug. Now, to turn the whole question around, what advantage is there to using an error code over an exception?

Comment: @Winston I agree about enforcing the check, which is why an option type is a better solution here – it lets the check be enforced by the type system. To some extent the same is true for values where you are *sure* that they are correct. “What advantage is there in using an error code over an exception?” – Less boilerplate code.

Comment: @Winston That said, your arguments are good enough that I would post them as comments on Eric’s blog post.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, certainly option types would solve the case of `parseInt` but what about `sendEmail`? `sendEmail` wouldn't have a return value of interest but we'd still like to enforce the check. However, I'm sure a good solution can be found to that problem as well. I don't think exceptions are perfect, I just think they are better then returning error codes. I have to agree that catching exceptions can require more code (albeit depends a bit on language/exact context). I think enforcing the check is worth it.

Comment: @Winston `SendMail` isn’t a case of vexing exceptions though. It’s the “exogenous” type in his taxonomy, and the whole raison d’être for exceptions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, ah, true. I guess I don't see those categories as distinct as he does. Opening a file could return null just like TryParse can return false. I don't really see why he thinks they are in a different category.

Comment: @Winston Because file access can fail at every moment and you have no way of checking this, since the file system is inherently concurrent and non-transactional. For instance, there is no way (!) to reliably check whether a file exists and to work with that information, since immediately after the check the information obtained is obsolete. *This* is the relevant difference.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, but you could have OpenFile return null if opening fails and have boolean error codes on methods like read/write. I still don't see a difference. I could absolutely use error codes on file operations and still handle all those cases correctly. What's being contrasted there isn't exceptions vs error codes, but look before you leap vs ask for forgiveness.

Comment: @Winston Hmm. I’m having a hard time making a case here since file operations in C++ work exception-free just fine. I *thought* I had understood Eric’s argument.

Answer (score 14):

The first form is indeed misleading - you have no reliable way of knowing what that `bool` value means.

The second is better, as the parameter name (`everythingIsOk`) is descriptive enough.

In cases like these, however, I'd use this signature:

```
void DoSomething([some arguments]);
```

and throw an appropriate `Exception` if anything goes wrong.

I see two advantages to this approach:

- it doesn't mix inputs and outputs - I think it's nice that the list of arguments only contains those needed for the method to do its job
- in case something is not OK you can give extensive details about what went wrong (by throwing an appropriate type of `Exception` and/or by populating the exception's `Message`)

There's one scenario where I'd avoid this, though: if your method is called many times, the creation of the `Exception object may be expensive, resulting in a performance penalty. In most cases, however, this will not be a problem.

**Update:**

There's another possibility - returning a result object that has a `bool` property indicating success state. This is used for instance by .NET's `Regex.Match(...)` method (it returns a `Match` object that has a `bool Success` property).

Our method signature would be:

```
SomeResult DoSomething([some arguments]);
```

The caller could inspect the value of `SomeResult.IsSuccesful` to see if all went OK.

Comment: ...Except if this is being used in a multi-threaded context, re-using an exception would get _really ugly_.  I'd rather have guaranteed safety over (somewhat) smaller costs.

Comment: If your code is throwing exceptions repeatedly, your code is broken. Full stop. Exceptions are meant for exceptional conditions, not data validation.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: That's true in c#, but not in e.g. Python.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - that's not a general rule. After all, .NET v4.0 has a class called `ValidationException`. A Google search tells me that Java has one too.

Comment: @w0lf: That's the exception, though (pardon the pun). Validation exceptions like that are intended for use in places where there's nothing that the program can *do* about the fact that the data's invalid and the fact that it's invalid is an *exceptional condition* (in other words, there should be actual, bona-fide data validation at a higher level that somehow mistakenly passed this invalid value down).

Comment: @NeilG: I can't speak to Python, so I'll gladly take your word for it, but Python isn't the language at hand in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Not a good idea IMO. Too much extra work and potential gotchas for something that is easily solved with good code comments.

Using `out` has implications if overloading such a function. The compiler cannot differentiate between `ref` and `out`.

Cannot pass properties as `out` parameters.

The calling code must declare and assign an "extra" variable associated with the `out` parameter.

Comment: +1 for great critics :) but what's the best solution in your opinion ? since method comments can't be seen when you are reviewing code but a variable name can clarify the purpose though we should add an extra line to our code ?

Comment: I'm assuming Visual Studio is being used here. Use the "///" to make your comments.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429452/auto-generate-function-documentation-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem here is not the code itself, its that there's no xml comments.  Seriously, commenting can go a long way.  I'd address that first.  Second, I'd look at the name of the method itself.  Is it doing a check?  Then CanDoSomething, IsSomething, etc would work.  If the method actually does "do something" and it's returning success or failure, then the name is fine.  Another alternative though might be an exception, depending on if the call should normally work or if failure is pretty common.

Regarding your suggested change with an out parameter, I couldn't do that.  Its not more expressive, and it forces callers to create a variable to hold the result.  In general, I think you should steer away from out / ref paramaters, they should be used pretty rarely.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key question here is whether the boolean being false indicates an 'exceptional' problem or not.  If it does, then forget the boolean and throw an exception.

Otherwise, you should separate out the validation from the execution:

```
if (canDoSomething([some arguments]) {
   doSomething([some arguments]);
} else {
   doSomethingElse([some arguments]);
}
```

and one might go to a factory method from there:

```
OperationToDoSomething operation = getAppropriateOperation([some arguments]);
operation.doIt();
```

Comment: ...which will fail horribly the instant `DoSomething()` depends on any external resource with a non-zero probability of intermittent availability.

Comment: ...which wasn't part of the question, and presumably would have been.  I would usually think of intermittently unavailable as an exceptional case though, at least at this level of abstraction.

Comment: I agree with @sharakan in this context. If you look at the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx Streams class, you can see how they prefer you to use the `CanSeek` property before you use the `Seek` method. This is very appropriate in many cases, but, as Michael points out, it could be a problem in a concurrency situation.

Answer (score 2):

How about naming the method CanDoSomething? Prefixing the method name Can, Is, Has, or Should implies a Boolean result.

Comment: It also implies that the method has no side effects though. So maybe you should implement that separately.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I find out I need more than one output from a method, this means:

1. My method does more work than it should, so I'll try to refactor
2. The data returned deserves its own struct/class, even an private
   one, with 2 or more properties for the real result of the operation
   and the flag for success, like:

Code:

```
private struct ComplexOperationResult
{
   public bool IsOperationSuccessful{get;set;}
   public MyRealData RealData{get;set;}    
}
```

The notations like Int32.TryParse are useful, but only for some infrastructure/base operations for a framework. Previous implementations (I'm not sure for the current one) of Int32.TryParse were only wrapper around try{int32.parse}catch{..}, because this is such a common operation, and to avoid a lot of boilerplate code.

So, if it's a public framework/library method, which will be used a lot, and exposing it otherwise will lead to too much additional repetitive coding for the consumers, go for TryXYZ pattern. Otherwise, introduce proper result structure, or refactor/rethink the method.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in terms of what the caller will look like, I feel the first one is better.

```
if(DoSomething())
{
    DoSomething1();
}
else
{
    DoSomething2();
}
```

vs.

```
bool b=false;
DoSomething(b);
if (b)
{
    DoSomething1();
}
else
{
    DoSomething2();
}
```

or even consider if you are calling this function in return statement, it could simply be called as

```
return DoSomething();
```

Comment: I'd rather rename b to success :) besides you can write the first one like this if(DoSomething()) instead of comparing it with true

Comment: Good suggestions Beatles. But my companies coding guideline do not allow the second . :-)

Comment: why they don't allow ? if I may ask

Answer (score 1):

Unless `DoSomething` is a trivial operation I would return a custom `Result` object that holds more information about what has happened. For instance:

```
public class Result
{
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
}

var result = DoSomething();

if (result.WasSuccessful)
{
   // 
}
else
{
    Console.Write(result.Message);
}
```

This way you can communicate back a lot more information than just a true/false value and make the properties have more meaningful values. The values I supplied are just illustrative, and obviously will change based on your requirements (as should the name of the "Result" object). It also means you can easily add extra properties/information later without breaking the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use RETURN VALUE in your case. 
Sometime it is really easy to use. like below ↓

```
.Append(MethodA()).Append(MethodB())......
```

I only use the OUT VALUE to save the status in each step(method) of a entire process , 
not for the result value.

And in C#4.0 you also can Cast the child class to parent by OUT keyword.

```
public delegate T Find<out T>();
Find<Cat> cat = ()=>new Cat();
Find<Animal> animal = cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different perspective: it's always easier to go asynchronous with the void version. I admit I'm biased by my own experiences which narrow on the parallel, non-deterministic environments, but in that context it's easier to think in autonomous independent async invocations. I don't say that my way of thinking is any better than that of anyone else though, consider it rather an opinion.

Comment: Could you expand on that? How does using `void` make it easier to go asynchronous?

Comment: When using void, the last parameter is typically the out param. When going async, it's easier to replace that with a callback reference.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a method's return value as in `bool DoSomething()` is the result that is *deliberately* intended by the programming logic. Put in other words, the return value of a method must represent the purpose of calling that method.

On the other hand, an output `out` parameter modifier (there is also a `ref` modifier in C#), implies an additional information that is generated during the method execution. This information is not the goal of the method, but still it is necessary to be supplied, because it may be used latter, or because it could be tedious to obtain that information a second time.

For instance, take the `bool int.TryParse(string value)` method. It implies that you are interested in **checking** if `value` is an integer, **regardless** of the actual integer it represents. In other words, you you ask if some string is a number and expect the computer to say: "yes, it is a n integer" or "no, it is not". The `out` parameter in this case represents the parsed integer, that is produced only if the parsing was successful.

Consider for instance the following code:

```
if (int.IsValidInt(value)) // an imaginary method
{
    int theInt = int.Parse(value);
}
```

Assume that the `int.IsValidInt(value)` method (that does not originally exist in .NET) checks if a string is integer by internally parsing it. It will produce an integer corresponding to the `value` parameter, but we will not be able to use it latter. So, if we need it, we will have to parse it again (via the `int.Parse`method), thus repeating the same operations already done by the `int.IsValidInt` alongside all the associated CPU and memory usage.

In such cases (like the one determining if a string represents an integer) we may have to produce a secondary result, that should be used latter. This is a good enough reason to use an an output parameter, as done in the `int.TryParse` method.
In regards to choosing which to be the  **return value**, I think it  should be the one that best represents the intentions of the method, and any additional data should be supplied as an output parameter.

According to the `int.Parse` vs. `int.TryParse` question, it depends on your case. If you need to to execute different logic depending on the input being a number or not, the `int.TryParse` seems more natural to use as it implies the logical branching:

```
if (int.TryParse(input, out parsed))
{
    int importantCalculation = parsed*someMagicNumber;
    /// other business logic
}
else
{
    // ask for input again
}
```

In case you need to **operate** with the input, you have a choice:

1. Use `int.Parse(input);` directly. This will cause an exception if the input is not valid, and you may have to handle the exception using `try-catch` blocks. Do this, if you need to show the user information for the error, or if invalid integers are unacceptable in this case.
2. Use the `int.TryParse` in combination with `if`-`else`. This can be useful if you need faster code (exception slow down the runtime), or if you have an alternative logic flow that can be executed.

Answer (score -1):

In this case is not requied to refactor but what if you need two output parameters?
Example:

```
public bool DoSomething(object parameter, out ref string ErrorDescription)
{
try {
...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
 return false;
}
ErrorDescription = "ok.";
return true;
}
```

If you would not use output parameter, you had to use any public property or create class as return type. This is easier.